# C# how to implement a class that works with controls and enable threading?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, treeview

I have written a class that fills a treeview for me. IN my project I need this treeview several times and I don;t want to copy paste my code, so I decided to create a class that fills the treeview for me.

On some forms I want to use a thread to fill the treeview. This is because sometimes it can take some time to load the data and fill the treeview.

In my treeview-class I pass the treeview in the constructor. At the moment I want to fill the treeview, I call the `LoadTreeview()` method.

I'd like to call the `LoadTreeview` method on a thread, but when I do this I get the exception that the treeview is created on another thread. Which is logic off course. But I was wondering, what is the best way to create a custom class that works with controls and you want to use this class in a thread?

Do I need to write this code on every 'GUI-action'?

```
treeview.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
  treeview.Nodes.Add(MyNode);
})
```

Or are there other (smarter) ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your and Levisaxos' solutions will prevent the crash but you should really benchmark the runtime performance of this. The problem is that if you insert lots of nodes to the treeview and each node is inserted through Control.Invoke your code will not be doing much but synchronizing to the UI thread. If this is the case you should consider to separate loading the data that is needed to create the nodes for the treeview from the actual insertion of the nodes. Instead load the data asynchronously and then synchronously insert all nodes at once.

Comment: you shouldn't ofcourse add nodes via the invoke control.  You invoke the TreeView and add the nodes in the thread. Then set the treeview to a property and fetch it (via invoke if needed) from the other class again.

Comment: So, if I understand you correcetly: First load all the data in a seperate thread, and when you have that data, create the nodes in the treeview (on the UI thread).

Comment: @Martijn: That's how I would do it. Of course other solutions are valid too. Go with the one you feel most comfortable with and the have a look at the performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
public delegate TreeView updateLabelDelegate(TreeView view);
private TreeView InvokeTreeView(TreeView view)
{
    if (view.InvokeRequired)
    {
        view.Invoke(new updateLabelDelegate(InvokeTreeView), new object[] { view });
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        return view;                
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you. This is how I am handeling Async operations.

[edit]
Depending on how you want to use it.
In a thread:

```
public TreeView thistreeviewsucks;
void SomeThread()
{
     TreeView tv = new TreeView();
     tv.Items.Add("something");
     //upon completion
     this.thistreeviewsucks = InvokeTreeView(tv);
}
```

As far as I know this will work.

Comment: Thnx. And the method the delegate points to, is in the same class?

Comment: Sorry forgot to edit. The method in the delegate points to the property it's in! see edited version!

Comment: I don't get it completely, How do you use this further in your code? What if you want to add nodes in a thread?